# Removing brackets and quotes from matrix in python

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, matrix

I'm trying to remove the brackets and quotes from a matrix of periods in python. I can't figure it out though. Everyone says to use `','.join(str(x)for x in list` but I don't know how to implement that into a list of lists. Can anyone help?

```
matrix=[]
for row in range(8):
    matrix.append([])
    for column in range(8):
        matrix[row].append('.')
print('\n'.join(str(p) for p in matrix))
```

That yields:

```
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']
```

I just want 8x8 of just periods...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are still printing nested lists. Join the nested lists too:

```
print('\n'.join(' '.join(p) for p in matrix))
```

or, perhaps a little simpler to follow:

```
for row in matrix:
    print(' '.join(row))
```

Demo:

```
>>> print('\n'.join(' '.join(p) for p in matrix))
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . .
```